# When exporting an xml file from excel, dates are become 5 digit numbers

Tags: xml, excel

When exporting an xml file from excel, dates are become 5 digit numbers.
07/01/2010 becomes 40185.
Same thing happens when I change the format of the cell from date to general.
Any ways to match the 5 digit number to the date?
Or someway to keep the date field in the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as floating point numbers. On Windows, the integer part is the number of days since January 1st, 1900 (midnight), the fractional part shows the time. So `.0` is midnight, `.5` is noon and `.99999` is `11.59.59 PM`.

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094

N.B.: On the Mac, Excel uses January 2nd, 1904 as the starting date (if you're curious about this, read [My First BillG Review](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html) by Joel Spolsky, which doesn't quite explain what's going on here but is an awesome read), but you can still transfer files between Mac and PC because the date format is stored in the Excel file.